# SyntaxError: invalid syntax Django NAME settings.py

Tags: python, django

I'm brand new to Django and SQL so I'm running through the polls tutorial. The problem is I keep getting a sytax error when I set the NAME in settings.py then run python manage.py syncdb.

```
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': /home/silight/Desktop/Python/django/first (BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

This is the relevant output from my terminal.

```
  File "/home/silight/Desktop/Python/django/poll/poll/settings.py", line 61
    'NAME': /home/silight/Desktop/Python/django/first (BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is the explanation from the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/).

```
NAME – The name of your database. If you’re using SQLite, the database will be a file on         
your computer; in that case, NAME should be the full absolute path, including filename, 
of that file. If the file doesn’t exist, it will automatically be created when you 
synchronize the database for the first time (see below).

When specifying the path, always use forward slashes, even on Windows (e.g.     
C:/homes/user/mysite/sqlite3.db).
```

It is probably something stupid, but if you could point what I screwed up to me I would be very grateful.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the quotes:

```
'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': "/home/silight/Desktop/Python/django/first/db.sqlite3",
    }
}
```

As simple as that, hope this helps!

Comment: #facepalm Of course it is. You know how long I researched this. lol.

Comment: Not sure who down voted, I don't have the reputation to do that. This answer worked great, just had to wait four minutes to accept it.

Comment: because you ninja edited the answer within the five minutes editing period (your original/previous answer was nonsensical); I can't revert my downvote now because my vote is locked, if you edit the answer I will revert the downvote.

Comment: Edited now. The first time i just added quotes without checking what the string was haha

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'NAME': '/home/silight/Desktop/Python/django/first/db.sqlite3',
```

However you should really learn the basics of programming in Python before you start learning/using Django.

Comment: I am sorry, why do we need the closing bracket at the end?

Comment: @thefourtheye: no you don't, that's a typo